# How do you detect if there is plain text preceding an element?

Tags: html, css

I have some HTML DIV elements that contain a narrative style of form. For instance:

```
<div class="narrative">
    My name is <input type="text"> and I am <input type="text"> years old.
</div>
```

Is there a way to detect with CSS if there is plain text before the first `<input>` element so I can add a left margin? If not, suggestions for ways to do this without having to class that first input or wrap the plain text in a span?

It won't always be preceded by plain text:

```
<div class="narrative">
    <input type="text"> is <input type="text"> years old.
</div>
```

Comment: CSS applies styles to HTML. It can't "detect" anything.

Comment: Even if CSS could detect text nodes, there wouldn't be a difference between your two snippets because the whitespace in your second snippet constitutes a plain text node. Then again, I'm just being a nitpick.

Comment: @Diodeus - I understand that. My question is semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS can only select elements, not individual text nodes within elements.  This is something you’d have to do through DOM scripting and CSS.

Comment: I don't really have access to JS in this specific use case, so it's got to be a CSS-only fix. To me that means I may need to wrap plain text in span tags.

Comment: Ah.  In that case, yes, you’ll have to wrap the text nodes in `span` or some other semanticless inline element.  In this case `span` is probably your best bet.  Best of luck!  I do not envy you your markup task.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is (ideally, clearly not respected in all cases) for presentational purposes only. What you need to add a margin on your `input` element is JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's not a CSS way to determine if the input is preceded by text.
You can use the [first-child](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child) pseudo class to target the first input of each narrative block:

```
.narrative input:first-child {
   margin-left: 20px;   
}
```

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/TZCK8/).

Comment: Unfortunately that's not going to work in the case of my second example above. It would add a margin to the input when there is no preceding text, throwing it out of line.